# Generics and challenges on the Parser Front

Tags: c#, generics

If you have:

```
F(G<A,B>(4));
```

does this mean that the user wants to call a method F with 2 parameters that result from comparing G and A, and B and the constant 4?

Or does it mean call F with the result of calling generic method G using type parameters A and B and an argument of 4?

Comment: The second one!, The inner G<A,B>(4) will process first then the call for F() will be performed

Comment: The second one of course

Comment: why do you think it's the 2nd one?

Comment: You should read section 7.6.4.2 of the C# spec.  It discusses that exact example.

Comment: Haven't read it yet, but I typed up some code and it turns out it looks for the generic method first. It gives this error: "The variable 'G' is not a generic method. If you intended an expression list, use parentheses around the < expression.
", if you intended to use boolean expressions as arguments to a method then you need to write it like this:
F((G<A), B>(4));

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I tried it out just to be sure. It turns out this works just fine:

```
void F(int x) { }
int G<T, U>(int x) { return x; }

class A { }
class B { }

void Main()
{
    F(G<A,B>(4));
}
```

But this produces a number of compile errors:

```
void F(bool x, bool y) { }

void Main()
{
    int G = 0, A = 1, B = 2;
    F(G<A,B>(4));
}
```

> The type or namespace name 'A' could not be found (press F4 to add a using directive or assembly reference)
>
> The type or namespace name 'B' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> The variable 'G' is not a generic method. If you intended an expression list, use parentheses around the < expression.

So the answer is that the expression `F(G<A,B>(4))` is interpreted as a generic function call. There are any number of ways to force the compiler to treat this as a single function call of two parameters: `F(G<A,B>4)`, `F((G)<A,B>(4))`, or `F(G>A,B>(4))`, just to name a few.

Answer (score 6):

You should read 7.6.4.2 of the C# spec, which deals with grammar ambiguities and discusses this example almost verbatim. To quote:

> If a sequence of tokens can be parsed (in context) as a simple-name (§7.6.2), member-access (§7.6.4), or pointer-member-access (§18.5.2) ending with a type-argument-list (§4.4.1), the token immediately following the closing `>` token is examined. If it is one of
>
> (  )  ]  }  :  ;  ,  .  ?  ==  !=  |  ^
>
> then the type-argument-list is retained as part of the simple-name, member-access or pointer-member-access and any other possible parse of the sequence of tokens is discarded.

Here, `G` is a simple-name and the question is whether `<A,B>` is to be interpreted as a type-argument-list as part of this simple name.

There is a `(` after the `>`, so the fragment `G<A,B>` is the simple-name of a method. The method is a generic method with type arguments `A` and `B` and an argument of 4. `F` is therefore a method with a single parameter.

One interesting thing to note is that this is a case where the compiler does not consider any alternatives if parsing fails. As you can see from p.s.w.g.'s answer, even if the only valid interpretation is one where `F` is a method that takes two parameters, it is not considered.